# NameError: global name 'imfilter' is not defined

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, module, scipy

I am trying to use [imfilter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imfilter.html) and, despite of upgrading to 0.18.1 version, I cannot use it:

```
>>> import scipy
>>> blurred_arr = scipy.imfilter(arr, "blur")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'imfilter'
>>> blurred_arr = scipy.misc.imfilter(arr, "blur")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'misc'
>>> blurred_arr = imfilter(arr, "blur")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'imfilter' is not defined
>>> scipy.__version__
'0.18.1'
```

I am not an expert in Python, so I feel that I am asking something really silly here...Can you help please?

Comment: Your first example says `spicy` not `scipy`.

Comment: Autocorrect @leaf, my code is with `spicy`, that's why I got a -1? :) BTW thanks, edited! ;)

Comment: Did you try `from scipy.misc import imfilter` ?

Comment: @khelwood that's it. Thank you. I think I should delete the question now, right? It has a negative score! If you want you can post an answer, if you do so, please explain why the other methods failed... :)

Comment: Up to you. Doesn't seem like a bad question to me. =)

Comment: Well if I delete the question @khelwood I won't be sure why your suggestion worked and why my attempt failed. I would encourage you to post an answer with the solution and with a reason for that! ;) Learn the man to fish, don't just give him a fish.

Comment: What's the problem here. Your doc-link says it's ```scipy.misc.imfilter``` and you imported as it were ```scipy.imfilter```. Everything else are just python import-styles.

Comment: @sascha the problem is me, but now khelwood taught me how to fish and, hopefully, you won't see any questions like this from me again, which might seem a piece of cake in the eyes of an experienced Python programmer! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `scipy.misc` is its own module, then it has to be imported explicitly.

Either:

```
import scipy.misc
...
scipy.misc.imfilter(...)
```

or

```
from scipy.misc import imfilter
...
imfilter(...)
```